# How to use angularjs multiple modules in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have been recently using angular js to code an project that uses asp.net mvc. I can not use angular module in a view while using in this view's layout page. Is there any solution for this ? Or can i use a controller in view while using another controller in this view's layout page on same module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lucky, I've been recently dealing with this issue.

Read this [article](http://shrestha-manoj.blogspot.com/2014/06/can-angularjs-have-multiple-ng-app.html) it helped my a lot at the first place.

Here is my solution, I was trying to keep kind of separation of modules:

I have defined one global module ng-app=”appRoot” and then as advised in article another modules are identified by ID tags.

```
<body ng-app="appRoot">
   <div id="appHeader">
   </div>
   <div id="appBody">
       @RenderBody()
   </div>
</body>
```

Then I simply inject modules to appRoot

```
angular.module('appRoot', ['appHeader','appBody']);
```

In my application each View has their own separate module, so I do:

```
angular.module('appSampleView', []);
angular.module('appBody', ['appSampleView']);
```